# Adding field of intersected polygons in points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersection, point-in-polygon

I have some points and polygons in an area. I want to add a field in those points that tell what polygons have been intersected by those points and not only what polygons but a specific attribute of those polygons.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer attributes between features using [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm) in ArcGIS Desktop.

Make sure that your data use the same coordinate reference system before using the Spatial Join tool.